# Find multiple rows based on common columns conditon

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have table like this below

```
OrderNo | item | price | customer
-----------------------------------
1      |  itemA  | 10   | customerA

2      |  itemB  | 20   | customerB

3      |  itemC  | 22   | customerC

1      |  itemA  | 10   | customerD

2      |  itemD  | 15   | customerD

4      |  itemB  | 20   | customerB

4      |  itemD  | 15   | customerB
```

I need to find common `OrderNo` for a given `List<Map<item,price>>`
I have composed query like below.

**Case 1**:

```
Select OrderNo from table tl where item in ('itemB' ,'itemD') and price in ('20','15') GROUP By OrderNo Having count(OrderNo) > 1
```

**comment**: works fine gives 2 record orderNo 2 & 4

**Case 2**:

```
Select OrderNo from table tl where item in ('itemB' ,'itemC') and price in ('20','22') GROUP By OrderNo Having count(OrderNo) > 1
```

**comment**: works fine gives 0 record

**Case 3**:

```
Select OrderNo from table tl where item in (itemA ,itemB) and price in (10,20) GROUP By OrderNo Having count(OrderNo) > 1
```

**comment**: incorrect result gives 1 record instead of 0. because itemA and itemB orderNo are different. it is giving 1 because there are multiple itemA records. but i want 0. since itemA orderNo != itemB orderNo

and also I have `List<Map<item,price>>` it can grow upto 100. what is the best approach in JPQL/Criteria Builder to achieve all 3 cases?

self join can be one approach but I am not sure how to have dynamic `self join` based on `List<Map<item,price>>` size in JPQL or Criteria Builder.

Comment: why is that incorrect? - from the data it looks fine, there are two, just on different customers - so maybe you have to add customer to your group by -

Comment: what i mean is, it is not what i expected.there is no query on customer why it will consider and give? . it is giving 2 because there are 2 rows with   (itemA ) without checking for itemB itself  it has 2 rows. but actually itemA orderNo and itemB orderNo  are not exactly same.

Comment: customer is something independent. it may or may not be same for each orderNo. so i cannot co relate with that..

Comment: on your case 3 you have 4 rows which pass your criteria.... when grouped there is order number 1, 2, 4 ... when you apply your having only order number 1 is available.

what do you expect to happen ?

Comment: my requirement is i need common orderNo for a given list of items. this query is not meeting my expectation. i need to write new query or modify this to meet my expectation. case 3 i want 0 matching. since itemA and itermB orderNos are different. but it is giving 1 record..negative case..

Comment: the 1 record it is giving is ---- 1 |  itemA  | 10  ----- the only difference is customer number...